… she had run back in the direction ____ she had come
How should I analyze and determine which options are correct in this question about relative clauses?

I saw a woman running toward me in the dark. Before I could recognize who she was, she had run back in the direction ____ she had come
A. where
B. in which
C. from which
D. from where


A native speaker would not say in the direction of northwest, but I would find C the most natural (he had come from the northwest).

I think many would also say D. And probably also "where he had come from", but that's not a choice.

None. It's a tautology. If you're saying "ran back" then it's tacit he's returning to where he came from. The sentence could end with the compass direction. It should also use the definite article because it's a specific stranger. Who is writing this garbage and then asking us to proof read it?

@Astralbee, Apologies for any confusion caused by the inaccurate question. My query stems from the following grammar choice question:
I saw a woman running toward me in the dark. Before I could recognize who she was, she had run back in the direction ____ she had come.
A. where
B. in which
C. from which
D. from where.
I modified the original content before sharing it, and I'm sorry if this caused any confusion. Could you please help me check if the actual question is acceptable now?
Thank you very much.

Right, so we say: to come from a direction. Therefore, that gives us: ran back in the direction from which she came. Always find the preposition that goes with the verb, then you can do: from which, about which, under which, etc. etc. etc. This is my comment under the question you asked. So, I could then get: Under which question did I  write a comment? See how it works?

There is actually a good teaching point here.

@Astralbee, The expression 'The stranger ran back in the direction from which he had come' focuses on the path or direction of the return rather than a specific place.

@yhlin if you went somewhere in a northerly direction, how could you go back any way but south?

@Astralbee, Hi， Thanks a bunch for your feedback! It got me thinking about how we use words. I get what you mean—when someone says "ran back," it already means they're going back to where they came from, so saying "in the direction from which he had come" is usually not needed. But sometimes, repeating things can make them stand out more, like in the example "The stranger ran back in the direction from which he had come, as though he realized he had omitted something.". I really enjoyed our discussion, and I hope we can talk more like this later on!

@Astralbee There are many factors at play. The poor Engish in"ran back in the direction of northwest" can be: ran back in the northwesterly direction from which he had come. The main point being the use of "from which" and how that works.

The original sentence is so much better, what made you think adding of northwest was a good idea? Who speaks or even thinks like that in a similar situation?

I must express my regret for any bewilderment caused by my poorly constructed sentence, especially with the addition of 'of northwest,' which rendered it illogical. Following insightful feedback from numerous individuals, it became evident that the sentence contained both semantic and logical inconsistencies. I am deeply grateful for everyone's constructive criticism and valuable analysis. In particular, special thanks to Lambie for a thorough analysis of relative clause grammar and to Astralbee for identifying the contradictions in the sentence's semantics.

The answer is C

C. I saw a woman running toward me in the dark. Before I could recognize who she was, she had run back in the direction from which she had come

Why? Because we say: to run back from a place or direction.
This may be jumping ahead but I answered this question a while back on ELU.
Here's the point:
The trick to knowing how to use; of which, at which, in which, to which, from which is to analyse the prepositional phrases, phrasal verbs, verbs and prepositions:

He /spoke of/ war and peace and many other topics that day.
The topic /of which he spoke/ was complex.
The verb here that means to speak about a topic is /to speak/ of a topic/: to mention

The party /at which/ he spoke/ was noisy.
Phrase: A party is held /at a place/. It is implied.

The situation /in which/ we found ourselves was dire.
Phrase: /to find oneself /in a situation.

The bonds /from which/ we broke free were tight.
phrase: to /break free/ from bonds.

The town /to which/we were driving was 50km away.
phrase: to /drive/ to a place.


Summary (and not a complete answer but a general one): The preposition depends on the verb that takes a preposition, a phrasal verb that includes a preposition, or it depends on the prepositional phrase used. Also, there are many other prepositions that can be paired with which: under, during, about, over, etc.

thank you very much for your help.

@Yhlin It's funny that most of my answer was given upvotes on ELU.

@ Lambie,  Thanks for sharing! Can't wait to chat more in the future. Cheers!

@Yhlin I can see you were not interested in a comprehensive answer to this. This is not a chat, by the way. :) check it out: 28 upvotes! https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/322836/how-to-correctly-apply-in-which-of-which-at-which-to-which-etc/322866#322866

@ Lambie, If my words seemed inappropriate in any way, please do forgive me and accept my sincerest apologies. My reply was intended to express my gratitude and a genuine desire for more discussions and opportunities to learn.

@Mari-LouA Well, you've put it to rights.

@Yhlin Nowhere did I suggest inappropriateness.

@ Lambie, As Astralbee astutely noted, 'If you traveled somewhere in a northerly direction, the only way to return would be southward.' This observation is quite pertinent, highlighting that the previous phrasing indeed suffered from both semantic and logical flaws. The correction should clearly indicate the direction opposite to the one initially taken. For instance: 'A stranger dashed back toward the southeast, the precise opposite direction from which he had arrived in the northwest.'

@Yhlin Now your question reads: Before I could recognize who she was, she had run back in the direction ____ she had come. = Before I could recognize who she was, she had run back in the direction from which she had come. Of course, if you go north, you go back by going south. BUT: your question is NOT even about that. It's about A, B, C or D in terms of the question as edited by Mary-Lou.

@ Lambie, Definitely! As you are aware, the question centered on the choice of relative pronouns and adverbs in attributive clauses, with complications arising from my contextual description in the original post, particularly the phrase 'of northwest.' I am indebted to fellow users for their assistance and insights, as the discussions on these subjects have enriched my understanding of English usage and significantly contributed to my language learning journey.

The sentence was not grammatical. So, your question was invalid as it was. Now, that Mary-Lou edited it, it is grammatical AND valid and I have answered by choosing "from which" and explained to why it now works and how to use these forms with other prepositions. It was never about adverbs, but about a complex relative clause using which and a preposition.

I apologize for any errors and am eager to embark on an ongoing journey of learning, improvement, and refinement.

You don't need to apologize for errors. That's not the point. Since you are not interested in what I had to say, so be it.

@ Lambie, Dear Lambie: Please be assured that my initial lack of further follow-up did not reflect a lack of interest in your analysis. I deeply value such exchanges and am committed to improving my responses with more detailed professional discussions from now on. I am truly sorry for any misperception or negative feelings that my lack of follow-up may have inadvertently caused. Thank you once again for your invaluable guidance and understanding.
